# PayPal Multiple IPN Setup in Civicrm

Tags: civicontribute

A nonprofit entity introduces other nonprofits for social awareness.

Nonprofit entity is willing to use Civicrm in a way that their member Nonprofits can setup their donation pages with their own PayPal IPN/Account for Donation collection. This way the donation will go directly to respect nonprofit.

Is this scenario possible to setup Multiple PayPal IPN/URL for each nonprofit member to collect the donation?

Thank you kindly and please advise.

Rizwan Ashraf

Answer (score 3):

Its possible to have payment processor of same type i.e it is possible to have more than one paypal payment processor in CiviCRM. You need to make sure you include correct payment processor on contribution or event page and also configure paypal ipn on each paypal account correctly.

https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/payment-processors/paypal-standard#assign-this-processor-to-your-contribution-or-event-registration-pages

https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/payment-processors/paypal-pro#assign-this-processor-to-your-contribution-or-event-registration-pages

Comment: Would you have a working example? document/URL where I can learn more about it please? Thank you!

Comment: amended to my answer